# How to find hydrogen atoms concetration from a doping profile?

Tags: experimental-physics, semiconductor-physics

Hydrogen atoms passivate dopant atoms. I want to find hydrogen concentration from a calculated dopant profile for a p-type silicon Schottky junction. Does anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: Do you know the actual doping profile to compare to an electrical measurement of the doping?

Comment: Yes, it was found based on C-V measurement.

Comment: That gets you the active dopant profile, so do you have the atomic concentration profile of the dopant? Then compare electrical (active) vs atomic…

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question. No, I do not know the actual doping profile.